# How to build classic business application in WPF (like in WinForms)

Tags: c#, wpf

I consider to rewrite one of our application in Oracle Forms to C#/WPF (about 15 forms and a few of libs). I read a lot about pros/cons of WPF and I think it's the right way. But I have a one problem. There is no MDI pattern like in WinForms. 
Nowadays I create new apps in C#/WinForms. Every app usually has main form with menu, login screen, buttons on main form which open other forms, etc. How to achieve this in WPF? I don't need multiple forms in a time. Generally I create MDI application and open every form in this window (maximized, only one form in a time on screen) - its has common status bar and title bar.
In WPF each window is separated and independent. Do I have to hide main window, open new window (new form), copy application title between windows ? It's a little bit strange way.
I know that I can use pages or open content in tabs, but I'm not sure is a good way. I also know about PRISM, but it looks like a big framework - I'm not sure I need it for this medium size app.

Is WPF only suitable for small application or maybe there is a good pattern to build bigger business software?

Comment: I would start by googling [first wpf application](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=first+wpf+application&oq=first+wpf+application&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j60j0l2j62.4433j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and you will find a load of tutorials that will pretty much give you a good explanation. I say this in relation to your first question of "How to achieve this in WPF"

Comment: I did it but this first wpf applications are the simple ones - one form, no menus, etc. Many answers to MDI alternative in WPF are to use tabs, but I'm looking for sth else.

Answer (score 1):

You can host several controls in one window using a `ContentControl`. I do this all the time and works like a charm. It has usability benefits over both MDI forms and using several windows in my opinion. You do not need to pull in PRISM to do this.

Try something like this

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:LoginViewModel}">
            <userControls:LoginView />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MainViewModel}">
           <userControls:MainView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main project I work on is a WPF business application. We use a ribbon menu and host our views in tabs.

There are some frameworks that will give you a pseudo-MDI look and feel. [This is one example](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/)

Comment: It's a interesting idea but not sure good for project I'm working on. One of our goal is evolution not revolution. Currently application is used by about 200 departments. If we change everything they will be lost in space :)
On the other hand the basic form they are working with is full of informations and each inch of space is important. Using ribbons and tabs will take a lot of it.

Comment: pasted a link to a wpf mdi project if you're interested.